# Configurations in SPFx Extension for CommandSet, Application Customizer and FieldSet

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I have created a solution for Sharepoint Online which needs some confiugration like clients website URL. we are using all the three types of extenstion

- Command set
- Field Set
- Application Customizer

I want to create a single package which can be deployed on multiple customers, but there configuration will differ.
What is the correct way to take such configuration?

Answer (score 0):

App settings for the SharePoint Framework:

1. https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/sharepoint-framework-app-settings
2. https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-app-settings

Comment: Hi Tracy, 
I need the configuration mainly for the SPFX extensions. Also, they should be dyanmic in the sense, if i build the spfx file then i should be able to deploy the same at multiple client location without ever building the binary. I should be able to configure the spfx extension settings somewhere in the UI of sharepoint or at app catalog?

Comment: I agree, the answer does not explain how to expose configuration in the UI.